# Compare and emphasise on the incident happened `Before`

Tags: difference, adjectives, parts-of-speech, comparison, comparative-constructions

Suppose person-1 has achieved a milestone today and person-2 achieved two years ago.

Now how can I emphasise on this time difference? Since `Before` is not an Adjective it doesn't have Comparative or Superlative degree.

I've some ideas like:

- Person-2 has achieved this `long` before
- Person-2 has achieved this `way long` before
- Person-2 has achieved this `way too much` before

Which option would express the sense more appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

[Before](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before) can be used as an adjective, but its common use is as a conjunction ("A had achieved that before *B did*"). For this sentence, the emphasis can be achieved by using "way before B" or "long before B".

You may want to consider the following alternatives:

- Person-2 has achieved this *long ago* (informal superlatives: *long long ago*, *ages ago*) - This is not a conjunction and does not compare to B.
- Person-2 has achieved this *earlier* (superlatives: *much earlier*, *way earlier*). Can be made comparative: "way earlier than B".

Comment: If  `Before` can be used as adjective, what are its comparison forms?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ELL StackExchange. :)

I would go with "long before" for written communication. "Way long before" seems to me a bit unidiomatic and more appropriate in spoken communication. Some other words you could use instead of "long" that come to mind are

- much before
- so much before
- very much before
- so very much before (The amount of emphasis here is a bit superfluous, but it's not incorrect)
- way before

Instead of "before" one could use "earlier".